# Yosef giving signs to his brothers

Tags: sources-mekorot, jewish-books, messiah, yosef, vayigash

Bereishit [45:3](https://www.sefaria.org/Genesis.45.3?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) states "וַיֹּ֨אמֶר יוֹסֵ֤ף אֶל־אֶחָיו֙ אֲנִ֣י יוֹסֵ֔ף הַע֥וֹד אָבִ֖י חָ֑י וְלֹֽא־יָכְל֤וּ אֶחָיו֙ לַעֲנ֣וֹת אֹת֔וֹ כִּ֥י נִבְהֲל֖וּ מִפָּנָֽיו"

In his book, [Vedibarta Bam](https://www.sie.org/templates/sie/article_cdo/aid/2865656/jewish/Dvar-Torah-Questions-and-Answers-on-Vayigash.htm), Moshe Bogomilsky, writes "When Yosef revealed himself to his brothers, he knew that they would be reluctant to believe him. He therefore gave them certain signs to prove who he was". This explanation is linked to a commentary from the אמרי יהודה, however, there are multiple versions available on HebrewBooks. Unfortunatley I am unable to locate this explanation from the אמרי יהודה. Does anyone know where to find this and what does the אמרי יהודה say more on this pasuk?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here](https://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=3824&pgnum=59)'s the source in Imrei Yehuda by R' Yehudah Leib Woll:

> ויאמר יוסף אל אחיו אני יוסף העוד אבי חי. הקשו המפרשים הלא כבר שאל להם על אביו והשיבו שהוא חי. ואפ"ל שיוסף אמר להם זאת לסימן שיאמינו לו שהוא יוסף. וזה ויאמר יוסף אל אחיו אני יוסף והסימן הוא העוד אבי חי. למה אני שואל רק על אבי אם הוא חי ולא על אמי. כי יודע אנכי שכבר מתה. ואם אין אני יוסף מאין יודע אנכי. והייתי צריך לשאול גם על אמי. והבן:"

He doesn't appear to say anything else on this particular verse.

Comment: Thank you. The follow-up question is what were these signs that Yosef showed his brothers? Are there any commentaries on that too?

Comment: @mvs One of the signs is that which is stated here by the Imrei Yehudah, which is that he spoke to them in a manner that showed that he was knowledgeable in the affairs of the family. The more famous sign brought in [Beresheet Rabbah 93:10](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Bereishit_Rabbah.93.10?lang=bi) is that he showed them that he was circumcised.

Comment: Thank you very much, @Harel13